# Cannot upgrade / use Nvidia drivers on Ubuntu 22.04.3

Tags: nvidia, 22.04, gpu-driver

Well I looked through all the solutions but nothing works. I really don't want to upgrade Ubuntu to 23.xx because the high-end 3D software version we are using isn't supported. This happened suddenly. The system wouldn't boot, went into recovery mode and then it booted but lost the NVIDIA driver. The system was 100% working all the time... now no NVIDIA driver and can't run any high-end software. Trying to install via GUI and Terminal.. no luck.. as to getting same error MSG:

```
Err:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/multiverse amd64 libnvidia-cfg1-535 amd64 535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]

...
```

Really need a fix as all the animation is now in limbo until I can get the software to run.
I'm using an AMD64 Ryzen 7950 system with an NVIDIA RTX 2060 Card.

Comment: Your details are a little vague (there is no Ubuntu 23); are you using the HWE kernel stack?  (ie. 6.5 kernel), if you are you may find an easy workaround is selecting an older 6.2 kernel at grub during boot and see if issue occurs there (I suspect not, and suspect your issue relates to dkms & 6.5 kernel but I don't know given your vague details).  An alternative if that is your issue is switching to the GA kernel stack (*I'm wrong if you're using that already; alas you didn't specify Ubuntu 22.04 product as install defaults can vary*) but that maybe extreme (*but is an option*).

Answer (score 1):

With Ubuntu running, try this:

Hit Win/Super key and begin typing 'Update' - a pinkish icon named `Software & Updates` will appear - select or click on it.

find the `Additional Drivers` tab and select any other than the "535" nvidia driver (not server version) and allow it to do the update...

Try a reboot.